# Plotting both horizontal and vertical point ranges simultaneously in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to plot both horizontal *and* vertical point ranges together on the same plot in `ggplot`. I understand that `geom_pointrange(...)` plots vertical point ranges, and that horizontal point ranges can be generated with `coord_flip(...)`, but I'm interested in putting both together on the same plot.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=sample(1:10,10),y=sample(1:10,10), x.range=1, y.range=2)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(x=x, y=y, ymin=y=y.range, ymax=y+y.range))
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(x=x, y=y, 
                      ymin=y-y.range, ymax=y+y.range, 
                      xmin=x-x.range, xmax=x+x.range))
```

Which of course produces the same output as above because the `xmin` and `xmax` arguments are ignored. Evidently, there is (was) a function `geom_hpointrange(...)` in `ggExtra`, but this package has been pulled as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is `geom_errorbarh` what you are looking for?

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +  
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = y - y.range, ymax = y + y.range)) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = x + x.range, xmin = x - x.range, height = 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! This will do it. After seeing your solution I realized that there is another way that uses `geom_errorbar(..)` with `width=2*x.range`, and `geom_errorbarh(...)` with `height=2*y.range`.

Comment: Nice trick with the `height = 0` to remove the errorbar whiskers.

Answer (score 3):

you can also call geompoint_range twice

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=y-y.range, ymax=y+y.range)) + 
  geom_pointrange(aes(xmin=x-x.range, xmax=x+x.range))
```

[image]